# Not pinging for one port to another port of same computer

Tags: networking

I have two LAN ports on same computer. One has 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3 but I am unable to `ping` from one to another.

Comment: wt u did till now to resolve your issue?

Comment: Are the interfaces connected to the same router? If not, I think there is a configuration to allow interfaces on the same PC to see each other (is disable by default, I think)

Comment: Please show us those failing ping commands and their output.

Comment: Commonly two ports are used for ***Link Aggregation*** to allow a higher throughput and offer a degree of redundancy. It would be useful to know what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Two lan cards in the same equipment, are supposed to be in different networks (unless you need to do more advanced configurations).

Configure one has 192.168.1.2/24 and the other as 192.168.2.3/24 and you will be able to ping them both.